# Where does the 'form-control' class get set when using autoForm, Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, meteor-autoform

I am engineering a custom `autocomplete` type for the `afQuickfield` in my Meteor project. The issue I am having is that when I set the `type="autocomplete"` on the `afQuickfield`, the `class="form-control"` attribute is missing. For all other field types, it is included.

I grepped `form-control` across the entire codebases for `meteor-autoform` as well as the `scss` and `js` directories of the `bootstrap` library. I only see occurances in the changelog and class definitions in scss/css.

I *could* just include `class="form-control"` in the `afQuickfield` definition, but that's a monkey patch and I'm not a fan of cutting corners.

Can anyone help me understand how `form-control` gets assigned in `autoForm` fields?

Here's my custom `autocomplete` code (it's a WIP, so no judging!). I'm just hoping to start with a text element with the proper `atts` so I can build from there.

```
// autocomplete.js
AutoForm.addInputType('autocomplete', {
  template: 'afAutocomplete',
  valueOut: function () {
    return this.val()
  },
  valueConverters: {
    stringArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToStringArray,
    number: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumber,
    numberArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumberArray,
    boolean: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBoolean,
    booleanArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBooleanArray,
    date: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDate,
    dateArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDateArray
  },
  contextAdjust: function (context) {
    context.atts.autocomplete = 'off'
    return context
  }
})

// autocomplete.html
<template name="afAutocomplete">
  <input type="text" value="{{this.value}}" {{this.atts}} />
</template>
```

Here's the code from the `type="text"` field for comparison.

```
// text.js
AutoForm.addInputType('text', {
  template: 'afInputText',
  valueOut: function () {
    return this.val()
  },
  valueConverters: {
    stringArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToStringArray,
    number: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumber,
    numberArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumberArray,
    boolean: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBoolean,
    booleanArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBooleanArray,
    date: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDate,
    dateArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDateArray
  },
  contextAdjust: function (context) {
    if (typeof context.atts.maxlength === 'undefined' && typeof context.max === 'number') {
      context.atts.maxlength = context.max
    }
    return context
  }
})

// text.html
<template name="afInputText">
  <input type="text" value="{{this.value}}" {{this.atts}}/>
</template>
```

As you can see the two are practically identical, yet the autocomplete version is without the `form-control` class in the actual HTML output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this seems to be a follow-up bug from `AutoForm`, because it should already throw the following error, when including `afInputText`:

> There are multiple templates named 'afInputText'. Each template needs a unique name

### What about the missing `form-control`?

This is correct in itself, because there is no `class` attribute on the `input` within the `afAutoComplete` template.

AutoForm built-in input types have no class attributes, because they will be [overridden by the themes](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform-themes/tree/main/bootstrap4/templates/bootstrap4/inputTypes).

For example the `text` input in the Bootstrap 4 theme looks currently like this:

```html
<template name="afInputText_bootstrap4">
  <input type="text" value="{{this.value}}" {{attsPlusFormControlClass}}/>
</template>
```

which itself is [defined as helper](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform-themes/blob/main/bootstrap4/helpers.js).

### So how to safely define the template?

Since there may be one day, where you will move from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 you can actually create your component + logic as defined above:

```js
// autocomplete.js
AutoForm.addInputType('autocomplete', {
  template: 'afAutocomplete',
  valueOut: function () {
    return this.val()
  },
  valueConverters: {
    stringArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToStringArray,
    number: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumber,
    numberArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToNumberArray,
    boolean: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBoolean,
    booleanArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToBooleanArray,
    date: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDate,
    dateArray: AutoForm.valueConverters.stringToDateArray
  },
  contextAdjust: function (context) {
    context.atts.autocomplete = 'off'
    return context
  }
})
```

```html
// autocomplete.html
<template name="afAutocomplete">
  <input type="text" value="{{this.value}}" {{this.atts}} />
</template>
```

and additionally create a separate template, that overrides the styling:

```html
<template name="afAutocomplete_bootstrap4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{this.value}}" {{attsPlusFormControlClass}} />
</template>
```

Important here is the combination of `afAutocomplete` and `_bootstrap4` which is used by AutoForm to determine the current template, as long as either the default template is set to `bootstrap4` or the current form uses `bootstrap4` as theme.

Comment: Should I define the `_bootstrap4` template in the `meteor-autoform-themes` codebase? I can fork it and include it in my root `/packages` directory? What's the likelihood that `meteor-autoform` will include an autocomplete that kicks ass and is styled in bootstrap 4, 5 and beyond? Thoughts?

Comment: The process of integration would be uncomplicated, since I currently manage the official Autoform and the themes. Let's discuss this in a new issue in the Autoform repo. I think this might bei interesting to other Autoform users as well.

Comment: Moved the conversation to https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform/issues/1700

Comment: It's good to note that the addition of `_bootstrap4` templates in `meteor-autoform-themes/bootstrap4/` requires that the `index.js` file be updated with the new template `import` path, too.